# convert long from register to char array in Python

Tags: python, linux, memory-management

I'm reading the registers of the memory on my 64bit Linux machine by using their virtual addresses in Python. However, my output from each register is (of course) a long value , for example 282584257676671

I'm a bit confused about PC architectures in general and I have some questions:

- Why has this long value 15 positions (and not 16?)
- Do the long values in a 32bit architecture have 7 positions then?
- A Linux memory page (4kb) is a pool of (4096/64) = 64 registers?
- Does a Linux memory page also have an address?
- Most important: How can I convert this long to a string in Python and how long will this string be?

Thank you!

Edit:

Thats what one can do in C:

```
unsigned char dest[4];
unsigned long int l;
dest[0] = l         & 0xFF;
dest[1] = (l >>  8) & 0xFF;
dest[2] = (l >> 16) & 0xFF;
dest[3] = (l >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

How can I do this in Python and will my char array also have the size of 4 in a 64 bit arch? or 8?

Comment: Hint: the number of digits in the decimal representation of a number does not indicate how many bits it is. Your example is at least 51 bits long, not 15.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do essentially the same thing in python.

```
dest = [0] * 4
l = some_integer
dest[0] = l         & 0xFF
dest[1] = (l >>  8) & 0xFF
dest[2] = (l >> 16) & 0xFF
dest[3] = (l >> 24) & 0xFF
```

To your other questions:

> - Why has this long value 15 positions (and not 16?)
> - Do the long values in a 32bit architecture have 7 positions then?

Because the number you're looking at here isn't padded with 0s, the only answer is that it will be as long as it needs to be! For example, if the memory address was `42`, when you print this in decimal it'll be 2 digits long.

Furthermore, you need to be careful about which base you're talking about. In hexadecimal, a 64 bit integer can be represented with 8 digits or less, like `0xFFFFFFFF` (two digits per byte). In decimal, a 64 bit integer can be represented with 20 digits or less, like `18446744073709551615`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering you last question (the most important one :D).

```
l = 282584257676671
s = str(l)

print(s)

>>> 282584257676671

print(s[0])

>>> 2
```